# Simple test setup with Selenium WebDriver fails

Tags: java, selenium, soapui

I'm just trying to execute a basic selenium test. Nothing special, just to make sure it works.
BUT is throws an exception.
What could I be doing wrong?

Of course I started the server using: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar`

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Selenium {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://www.google.de/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSeleniumWeb() throws Exception {
    //empty just for testing
    }
}
```

Throws:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.crimson.tree.ElementNode2.getTextContent()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.FileExtension.readIdFromInstallRdf(FileExtension.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.FileExtension.writeTo(FileExtension.java:61)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ClasspathExtension.writeTo(ClasspathExtension.java:64)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.installExtensions(FirefoxProfile.java:547)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.layoutOnDisk(FirefoxProfile.java:525)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:149)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:79)
    at de.coconet.soapui.selenium.setUp(selenium.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: It looks like it's finding an old XML Parser (Apache Crimson) which doesn't support the getTextContent() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nothing to do with your code. You have a classpath problem. Some classes depend on a different version of ElementNode2 than the one found first in your classpath.

If you look at [jarfinder](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.crimson.tree.ElementNode2) you can see that after JDK 1.4, this class is included in the Java runtime (rt.jar).

I suspect that you are using an older version of the JDK than the one that WebDriver was compiled against. WebDriver requires JDK 1.6+.